# Whats the correct format for the Apple Maps web snapshot overlay?

Tags: url, mapkit, url-parameters, apple-maps

I'm trying to create an [Apple Maps mapkit web snapshot](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/snapshots/create_a_maps_web_snapshot). What's the correct way to format an [overlay object](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/snapshots/overlay) to pass into the url?

I've ended up with the [following url](https://snapshot.apple-mapkit.com/api/v1/snapshot?size=640x275&teamId=2DS67Q47ES&keyId=Q5YUQ678YQ&scale=2&colorScheme=light&center=37.837514999999996%2C-122.538235&spn=0.016069999999996584%2C0.013949999999994134&overlays=%3Fpoints%3D37.8323%252C-122.5401%252C37.83761%252C-122.54399%26strokeColor%3D%2523935DFF%26lineWidth%3D2&signature=0ihzDoAq7LZvsKgiUBPWvssaCGTe7PVYMpFzMWiGNZpKZ0UJD6KFT_qWsERE6NPyq9KNHl8_gjJOnOCvEaA_rQ) where the object is formatted as follows:

`overlays=%3Fpoints%3D37.8323%252C-122.5401%252C37.83761%252C-122.54399%26strokeColor%3D%2523935DFF%26lineWidth%3D2`

Everything works fine in the URL except I don't understand the correct format to pass in the overlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually requires wrapping the json object in an array to work correctly.

Comment: Care to explain how?
I am working with annotations and got this but not working.

    $AnnotationsData = array(
      'point' => '37.78,-122.42',
      'color' => '449944'
    );
    $payload = "annotations=" + json_encode($AnnotationsData);
    $params[] = $payload;